# Finding $Ax=b$ given particular and special solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am given that the particular solution to a system of equations is $ x_p = (3,2,0) $ and the special solution is $ x_n = (2,5,1) $ and asked to construct a 2 by 3 system $ A \mathbf x = \mathbf b $

I know that for going about finding the particular solution  you would create the augmented matrix and convert to reduced row echelon form, however I'm not sure how to go about this when I'm not given a matrix.

Comment: It was worded as special solution in the problem. Maybe it is the homogenous solution, although I'm a little confused what the difference between the two is.

Comment: If the special solution is referred to the homogeneous solution then there are infinite choices of $A$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that special solution refers to the homogenous solution, where $b = 0$, we know that $Ax_n = 0$. From here, you could set up equations to solve for the matrix entries using the values for $x_n$. For instance, row 1's equation would look like:

$a_{11}(2) + b_{12}(5) + c_{13}(1) = 0$

However, as a previous comment states, there will be infinite choices of $A$ and $b$, given that the homogenous solution is not the zero vector.

Comment: Thank you! I that makes a lot more sense now.